Why test cases fail in Jenkins with null pointer exception though it runs successfully on local
Test case execution failure on Jenkins Node. Testcases are written in Java using Junit. My webpage is not loading. The web app and backend is running successfully on Jenkins machine, but still it fails to load the web page. But when it is run on local env it works fine.
Expected test cases to pass on Jenkins as it executed fine on local.

We can't help you with so little information. Can you share the relevant part of the code and the failure?

its because the ip addresses are different

Can you share more details about the specific issue that you are facing?
